# How to append data to state array?

Tags: react-native, jsx

I have a api that responds me with list of users , I use filters for user to filter the results , I use state in my api request and some of them are arrays I need to add selected filters to the array , but currently I am replacing the old state with the new one.

**this is my state:**

```
  this.state = {
   loading: false,
   dataSource: [],
   error: null,
   topics: []
  }
```

**This is my api call:**

```
  getLawyers = () => {
   fetch('https://www.someapi.com/posts?topics[]='+this.state.topics, {method: 
   'GET'}).then((response) => response.json()).then((responseJson) => {
   this.setState({
    loading: false,
    error: responseJson.error || null,
    dataSource: responseJson.data,
    dataSource: [
      ...this.state.dataSource,
      ...responseJson.data
    ],
    loadingMore: false
      });
     }).catch((error) => {
      this.setState({error, loading: false});
     });
    }
```

**and here is where the user selects topics to search:**

```
<Text onPress = {(text) => this.setTopic('topic1')}> Some Topic </Text>
<Text onPress = {(text) => this.setTopic('topic2')}> Some Topic </Text>
<Text onPress = {(text) => this.setTopic('topic3')}> Some Topic </Text>
```

**`setTopic():`**

```
setTopic(searchedTopic) {
 this.setState({topics: searchedTopic});
}
```

I want to add searched topics to array in state , intead of replacing it with old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`searchedTopic` is a string and not an array, therefore the correct answer should be:

```
setTopic(searchedTopic) {
 this.setState({topics: [ ...this.state.topics, searchedTopic ] });
}
```

With `...searchedTopic` each character would be added to the state topics. 
E.g.

```
["topic1", "topic2", "t", "o", "p", "i", "c", "3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will add the items of searchedTopic array into existing this.state.topics array.

```
 setTopic(searchedTopic) {
 this.setState({topics: [...this.state.topics, searchedTopic]});
}
```